# Library to collect electronic signatues with Adobe Pro

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have set up a library on my SharePoint 2010 site with 12 documents awaiting electronic signatures on a Adobe Pro letters.  Is there a way to avoid each signee having to save the document to their computer before the signature will take?